# Draw support and resistence using bokeh

Tags: bokeh

I would like to know how to draw a horizontal line in some prices to set some support and resistance in my charts, can i have some example how to do that, I was trying to use the line() but I still need to pass the x,y coordinates I would like to have something dynamic.

```
import pandas as pd
from math import pi
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
from bokeh.io import export_png

df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["period"])

inc = df.ohlc_close > df.ohlc_open
dec = df.ohlc_open > df.ohlc_close
w = 12*60*60*1000 # half day in ms

print(inc, dec, w)
#TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save"

p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", plot_width=1000, title = "Testing Graph")
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi/4
p.grid.grid_line_alpha=0.3

p.segment(df.period, df.ohlc_high, df.period, df.ohlc_low, color="black")
p.vbar(df.date[inc], w, df.ohlc_open[inc], df.ohlc_close[inc], fill_color="#D5E1DD", line_color="black")
p.vbar(df.date[dec], w, df.ohlc_open[dec], df.ohlc_close[dec], fill_color="#F2583E", line_color="black")
export_png(p, filename="plot.png")
```

Comment: Your question is too vague. Dynamic in response to what? What are "support" and "resistance"? Is this an annotation? You probably want `Span` instead: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/annotations.html#spans

Comment: looks like Span will work for my case i will give a try on it, ty.